# bash script to find specific text if same multple lines are present in a text file

Tags: bash, sed, grep, find

I want to write a bash script to copy one value from a text file. In the text file, i have some reapeated line . Example :

```
WIN [err]: fe I:35    A Q:24.17  si: 4554  INT:55.90 CA Mn A:61.00 B:44.45  INT:42.06

WIN [err]: fe P:880   A Q:26.89  si:  325  INT:12.12 CA Mn A:57.62 B:44.11  INT:39.56

some text line
some text line

"Line that i want to copy value:" WIN [err]: fe P:870   A Q:26.89  si:  325  INT: 5.5 CA Mn A:57.62 B:44.11  INT:39.06 

dec 2000 frs, 30.8 fs, 2029.95 ms/s
```

Now I want to display the INT value ex: 39.06 which is present in this line "Line that i want to copy value:". Please consider the stating line from 
"WIN [err] ....." I am new to shell scripting. As I have modified my text file. Now we are seeing that the string "INT: is present in some other lines also.
Can anyone help?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you want "the second to last line".  I believe you are asking for the value in the last line that matches WIN (in the example you give, these are equivalent).

```
awk '/^WIN/ {v=$NF } END {split(v,a,":"); print a[2]}' input
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably this can work:

```
awk -F'[: ]+' '$1=="WIN"{a=$NF} END {print a}' RS='[\r\n]+' file.log
```

Comment: Thanks to all, but i am getting some errors like command not found or sed can't read 39.06 etc. I am new to scripting. I have edited my question also so u can help me in better way. Plz refer my edited question.Thanks

Comment: Yes i tried but I was not getting any output. Script is able to run but it is not displaying any output.

Comment: thanks..able to print some value......i will try to print some other values with ur updated script